# DAX formula providing the previous value of a variable, sorted by a different variable

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2, containing the following information:

```
Table1: Sales
    
Date        Firm A  Firm B  Firm C
30-05-2022   100    200     300
29-05-2022  
28-05-2022   
27-05-2022   130    230     330
26-05-2022   140    240     340
25-05-2022   150    250     350
```

and

```
Table2: Dates

Relative day    Date
1               30-05-2022
2               27-05-2022
3               26-05-2022
4               25-05-2022
```

In my Power BI (PBI) desktop a slicer, allowing the user to select from a range of `Relative day`s (i.e. number of business days from today's date), is present.

What I want is to create a new measure, `Sales lag`, that contains the lagged value of sales for the individual firm, and for which the lagged value is based on the `Relative day` variable e.g.:

For the slicer set according to `Relative day=1`

```
           Sales    Sales lag
    Firm A  100     130
    Firm B  200     230
    Firm C  300     330
```

Please note that I (think I) need the measure to be based on the `relative day` variable, as the `Date` variable does not take into account business days.
I previously used a measure that I think was similar to:

`Sales lag =calculate(sum(Table1[Sales],dateadd('Table2'[Date],-1,day))`

While this measure provided the correct results most of the time, it did not in the presence of weekends.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want "Sales lag" to only show the sales ON the relative day or to show the sum of all sales SINCE the relative day? I provide a solution for the sum SINCE the relative day in my answer below, but if you would only like the sales ON the relative day, I can update the solution.

Comment: Hi @MattKocak, Thank you for providing an answer. I am sorry for the mistakes in my question that may  have caused the confusion of yours. I am interested in the solution where "Sales lag" shows only the sales ON the relative day. It may sound counterintuitive, but when the user selects e.g. Relative day=2 in the slicer, `sales lag` should show Sales as of per Relative day=3 . Also, I have edited the tables so as to provide more accurate information - in practice, there exist no blank cells in the `Relative day` column

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer accordingly, although I still use sample data where the "Firm" is all in one column rather than each firm having its own column. Would you please confirm whether your data for Table1 is as I outline in my answer? Or are the sales for the firms indeed populated in their own separate columns?

Comment: @CecilieSK did my answer solve your issue? If so would you mind accepting it as the solution and upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

I used some sample data structured slightly differently than you provide and took a stab at providing you with a solution. Find the sample data I used below and the `Sales lag` measure in the **Solution Measure** section.

**Table1**

| Date | Firm | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30-05-2022 | A | 100 |
| 29-05-2022 | A | 110 |
| 28-05-2022 | A | 120 |
| 27-05-2022 | A | 130 |
| 26-05-2022 | A | 140 |
| 25-05-2022 | A | 150 |
| 30-05-2022 | B | 200 |
| 29-05-2022 | B | 210 |
| 28-05-2022 | B | 220 |
| 27-05-2022 | B | 230 |
| 26-05-2022 | B | 240 |
| 25-05-2022 | B | 250 |
| 30-05-2022 | C | 300 |
| 29-05-2022 | C | 310 |
| 28-05-2022 | C | 320 |
| 27-05-2022 | C | 330 |
| 26-05-2022 | C | 340 |
| 25-05-2022 | C | 350 |

**Table2**

| Relative day | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-05-2022 |
| 2 | 27-05-2022 |
| 3 | 26-05-2022 |
| 4 | 25-05-2022 |

**Solution Measure**

```
Sales lag = 
VAR sel = SELECTEDVALUE(Table2[Relative day])
VAR dat = CALCULATE(MAX(Table2[Date]), Table2[Relative day] = sel + 1)

RETURN 
    IF(
        ISBLANK(sel), 
        "", 
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(Table1[Sales]), 
            ALL(Table2[Relative day]), 
            Table1[Date] = dat
        )
    )
```

**Sample Result**

[image: Sample Result]